# Advanced Installer - Install windows service for Solr5

Tags: solr, advanced-installer

I'm trying to create a Installation package using Advanced Installer , this package should install new windows service for Solr5. 
the windows service should run the solr.cmd file with start params.
and of course do stop with a given stop params.
can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Use NSSM. https://nssm.cc/

Comment: is there any way to do it with advanced installer features? i prefer to use the embedded features and not nssm.

Comment: nssm solve my problem after all thx